# How do I notice Google Search Console to stop checking my non-HTTPS and www- domain?

Tags: google-search-console

I have a website like mysite.com

And Google indexed 3 pages now:

1. `http://www.example.com` (with `www-`)
2. `http://example.com` (without SSL)
3. `https://example.com` (correct one)

I only need the `#3` and I have already set up correct 301 redirection from `#1` and `#2` to `#3` for days. I have also put `canonical url` for the page, pointing to `https://example.com`

However, Google is still fetching the two other URLs.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: When you say google is still fetching the two other URLs, do you mean that you are seeing googlebot in your server logs?

Answer (score 1):

Google will never stop checking your alternate URLs.  Googlebot will periodically crawl them.   Google Search Console will report any errors it finds with them.   This is perfectly normal, and there is nothing you can do to prevent either of those things from happening.

Google will eventually index only one of those URLs.  Even if Googlebot is crawling several versions of the URLs, it will find your redirects and index just the canonical version to which the redirects point.  It may take Google months to get to that point.  When I moved my site from HTTP to HTTPS, it took Google more than a year to index all the URLs as HTTPS.  For some reason it was still indexing HTTP URLs months after they were redirected.

If you no longer want to see errors from your `www` or HTTP URLs you can simply remove those properties from Google Search Console.  When you have everything redirected properly, GSC is unlikely to tell you anything worthwhile on your non-canonical properties.   The only reason I keep mine is for historical data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified #3 as your "preferred domain" in GSC settings?

> If you specify your preferred domain as http://www.example.com and we
>   find a link to http://example.com, we'll consider both links the same.
>   Learn more about setting a preferred domain. - From Google SC Settings.